# Android integrate google+ in app

Tags: android, google-plus

Can anyone used Google+ in android app? I searched about the same thing but I found nothing. If anyone have any idea or related code then please post here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no public API yet, but you can sign up for updates here:

https://services.google.com/fb/forms/plusdevelopers/

A basic Java library is available here:
http://code.google.com/p/javaplus/

And a basic PHP library here:
https://github.com/jmstriegel/php.googleplusapi

Comment: Beat me to it good sir. Looking forward to the API, can imagine some powerful functionality being built around the platform.

Comment: Thanks dgrant. Its helpful for initial stage. Can you explain in detail or share the real example here? Specifically for Android application. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to the Google APIs.
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/

You can create your application, and add several APIs to it (Youtube, Google+, etc).
There are several samples.

Hope its useful

Answer (score 0):

You can also try http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-api/

Comment: i saw there is library, how to implement g plus in android app? if you have any idea than help me pls.

Comment: pretty much the same way. In order to save some memory, though, you might skip all the depenedencies and implement OAuth yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Integration of Google Plus into your android application requires following prerequisites

1. Enable Google+ API on Developers Console and create credentials for your application authentication
2. Configuring Google Play Services in Eclipse
3. Create Android Application with Google Plus Sign In

You can check detailed step by step tutorail at

http://androidsrc.net/integrating-google-plus-sign-in-into-your-android-application/