# How to integrate Google + in my android application?

Tags: android, google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android integrate google+ in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869343/android-integrate-google-in-app)

How to make google + integrate in android application?
And i also saw the post something in my wall...

Thanx.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518150/is-there-already-a-google-api

Comment: What do you mean "add google+ integration". Can you please expand on what exact functionality you'd like to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-api/ (haven't tried it on android though)